# Heroku - compiled slug size is too large

Tags: heroku

I am getting the following error: `Compiled slug size: 3G is too large (max is 500M).`

I currently have only around 12MB of assets in my directory, as far as I can see.

I tried running `heroku run bash -a <my project name>` and then `du -ha --max-depth 1 /app | sort -hr`, and got the following:

```
384M    /app
377M    /app/.heroku
6.5M    /app/templates
16K     /app/.profile.d
8.0K    /app/__pycache__
4.0K    /app/runtime.txt
4.0K    /app/requirements.txt
4.0K    /app/README.md
4.0K    /app/Procfile
4.0K    /app/main.py
4.0K    /app/.gcloudignore
4.0K    /app/app.yaml
```

Specifically, I am not sure where the top two come from, and why they are so big. This also does not add up to 3.3GB.

I also tried `heroku repo:gc -a <my project name>` and I got: `Warning: repo:gc is not a heroku command.`

My requirements.txt file is made up of the following:

```
Pillow==8.4.0
transformers==4.36.2
fastapi==0.68.0
python-multipart==0.0.5
uvicorn==0.15.0
Jinja2==3.0.3
gunicorn==21.2.0
tokenizers
tensorflow-cpu==2.9.2
torch-cpu==2.1.2
flax==0.7.2
```

At first, I was just using `tensorflow`. Then I changed to `tensorflow-cpu` and it was reduced by 300MB. But I have no idea how to get rid of the extra 2.5GB. I am importing BlipProcessor and BlipForConditionalGeneration from transformers, maybe it's that? Is there any way to reduce the file size? Or maybe I could use Amazon S3 instead?